# Undefined Control Sequence. \citestyle Error MAC

Tags: errors, mac, undefined

[image: This was an attempt to use a test of the code. Notice, it also claims that \begin{document} is missing]

[image: The template is sample-siggraph.tex, located on Siggraph's website > Learn > Instructions for Authors]

1st Image: This was an attempt to use a test of the code.  Notice, it also claims that `\begin{document}` is missing.

2nd Image: The template is `sample-siggraph.tex`, located on Siggraph's website > Learn > Instructions for Authors.

I also tried working with the Commands/Preferences (since this is a Mac laptop)
and currently my PdfLaTeX Command configuration is: `"/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex"`
Before that, it was: `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`
Both of these do not work.

I have not used this program before this class at my University.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the first example works without problems; the second example cannot be built from the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The document can't be parsed upto the `\begin{document}` line, because it cannot find a command called `\citestyle`. That command is a part of [natbib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/natbib?lang=en) package, and it is referenced in the new *ACM LaTeX template documentation*, on page 19 of `acmart.pdf`:

> 2.10 Bibliography
>
> ACM uses natbib package for formatting of referencing ant the style ACM-Reference-Format. bst for BibTEX processing. You may disable loading of natbib by using the option `natbib=false` in `\documentclass`. However, it is not recommended, as well as the use of BibTEX styles other than `ACM-Reference-Format.bst`, and may delay the processing of the manuscript.

Thus I would suggest to download that package and try to compile again.